# MongoDB help getting all elements of a collection A not in collection B

Tags: mongodb

How do I write a mongo query to get all elements in collection A with specific parameters that are not present in collection B?

I have a collection called some_classes that looks like this:

```
{
 { 
    "docid": "someID",
    "_id": objectId(somenumbers),
    "type": "X",
    "id_code": {
        "first": "364",
        "second": "143",
        "third": "Apple"
    }, 
  { 
    "docid": "someID",
    "_id": objectId(somenumbers),
    "type": "X",
    "id_code": {
        "first": "364",
        "second": "143",
        "third": "MH"
    }
}
```

and I have another collection called master_classes that looks like this:

```
{
     { 
        "_id": objectId(somenumbers),
        "id_code": {
            "first": "364",
            "second": "143",
            "third": "MH"
        }, 
      { 
        "_id": objectId(somenumbers),
        "id_code": {
            "first": "364",
            "second": "143",
            "third": "ZH"
        }, 
    }
```

I need to get all elements in some_classes where docid="someID" and type="x" that do not have a matching "id_code" in master_classes.

Is there an efficient way to accomplish this? I'm thinking maybe I can accomplish this using aggregate and lookup, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm still researching. I'm new to mongodb queries. I started off with a DBCursor containing the elements I needed, but I don't think that's the right approach.

Comment: There is no join in mongodb. You should aggregate two colletions. Search for $lookup functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do queries across multiple collections at once in MongoDB. You will have to do two separated queries and use the [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) operator to filter out the results:

First you get all the different `id_codes` in `master_classes`:

```
const ids = db.master_classes.distinct("id_code")
```

Now you tilter out the results from `some_classes` that are already in the previous `id` variable:

```
db.some_classes.find({
    docid: "someID",
    type: "x",
    id_code: { $nin: ids }
});
```